# Suggestions for finding code to review, that is for CodeReview.SE 

Tags: code-reviews

Looking for suggestions on finding code to review, or to be more clear, code on SE sites with excepted working code -- to suggest be posted to [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/growing-code-review-one-idea) for optimization.

The source of this question was another question I posted on CodeReview.SE.meta

[Growing Code Review, One Idea... :-)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/growing-code-review-one-idea)

In which I got this reply:

---

> Sure, you can, as long as people are
> clear what code review is for --
> essentially, functioning, working code
> that needs to be improved in some
> subjective, perhaps even aesthetic,
> way.
>
> If the code is in any way broken or
> does not work, that is not the purpose
> of Code Review.
>
> [Jeff Atwood](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/136/jeff-atwood)

---

If anyone has suggestions on how to improve this question, just comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that posting code from any OSS software that is available on one of the many hosting sites would be a great way to:

1. Gain more exposure for that project
2. Improve the quality of code for that project

Of course, it would have to be posted by someone familiar with the code with specific questions/requests about the code in general. i.e. review for readability, performance, separation of concerns, etc.